# Node module doesn't work in Firebase hosting?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Node server and use Firebase hosting. The server uses the Node module **rss-to-json** for parsing a RSS feed to JSON.

When I test the server on my machine, the request works, but when deploying it doesn't work. It just loads forever and gives:

> "Error 503 first byte timeout"

**My code:**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const Feed = require("rss-to-json");

app.get("/feed", (req, res) => {
    Feed.load("https://www.reddit.com/.rss", function(err, rss) {
        res.send(rss);
    });
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**Have tried:**

Removed "node_modules" from "ignore" in firebase.json, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which payment plan is your Firebase project on?

Comment: Also, have you tried checking the value of `err` in your callback?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have the free plan and I don't get a value from err, it's just trying to load until the timout :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Spark payment plan, you can't make outgoing requests to services that aren't fully controlled by Google.  If you want to do this, you'll have to upgrade your project to the Blaze plan.  See the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) for more information.